# Silverstripe: Frontend form with file upload could overwrite existing files

Tags: silverstripe

I'm running into a small problem with a project of mine. I have a working frontend form that can be used to put an image into a dataobject and save it. No problem so far, but it's an avatar so when one of my users uploads avatar.png it could be overwritten by another user using the same filename. This is expected Silverstripe behavior, but in my case unwanted.

Is it possible to prepend a string to the image name, for example, the username (which is unique)? In a perfect world that would only happen on the front end of course, but I will settle for less :-)

Regards,
Joost.

Comment: What form field are you using for upload? FileField or UploadField?

Comment: I am using UploadField. That one sets replaceFile to one, so at present I am trying to extend Upload itself (and the inject it to replace upload) to force it to make a unique value.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. There is also a setting for Upload to rename the uploaded File instead of replacing! See http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Upload.html#_setReplaceFile
Maybe you have to suppress UploadField's overwrite warning. Good Luck, please post the result of your work ;)

Comment: I am exactly trying to do that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I found the following solution. The upload class has a setting, that lets you specify if the image will be replaced or if the image filename will be changed, and uploaded nonetheless. The funny part is that the default is set to not replace.

The formfield class that I am using is UploadField, which extends FileField, that uses the upload class. By default, the UploadField class sets the upload to replace the old file, using Upload->setReplaceFile(true).

I therefore decided to create a new upload class, and replace the old one with that:

```
class VBUpload extends Upload {
    public function setReplaceFile($bool) {
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'admin/')===false) {
            $this->replaceFile = false;
        } else {
            $this->replaceFile = $bool;
        }
    }
}
```

I only want the default working changed when called from the front end, and maybe there's a cleaner way to achieve that. But this one is working for me.

The only thing to do next is forcing the system to actually using the class, so I added this to the /mysite/_config/config.yml:

```
Injector:
  Upload:
    class: VBUpload
```

This probably can also be done with a normal extension, but I'll change that when the need arises :-)

Comment: Hello sir @jberculo, by any chance, we're you able to replicate it as an extension? I'm on SS4 right now and I can't seem to enable the overwriting feature in the admin CMS

Comment: No, sorry. The need did not arise :)